# How can I line up multiple tables side by side in Outlook email?

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email, line-breaks

I want to show some text in a "tag" inside an outlook email and the recommendation I got is to use tables like this (assuming that the text I want to show in a "tag" is MY TEXT

```
  <table style='background-color: blue'><tr><td style='padding:2px 5px'><b>MY TEXT</b></td></tr></table>
```

this works great but now I need to show multiple tags side by side and if i do something like this where I put one after an other, they show up on different lines.

```
  <table style='background-color: blue'><tr><td style='padding:2px 5px'><b>MY TEXT</b></td></tr></table>

  <table style='background-color: blue'><tr><td style='padding:2px 5px'><b>OTHER TEXT</b></td></tr></table>
```

Is there anyway to line this up side by side and not having a line break after each table within an Outlook email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table will work fine. A new table or table row will move the content vertically. A table cell (td) will place it horizontally

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Text</td>
        <td>Second Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've placed a more in depth example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Hexl/pen/NqyojZ)

Answer (score 0):

Just have one `<table>`. Hide a short cell with a `nbsp;` in between your two tables and set the top and bottom boarders of the cell to be blank/white/no borders.

You could also try using nested tables. That is to say one table inside another. Again you'd hide the borders of the outer table.

Lastly you could use the `div`s. This web page uses `div`s. Have a look at the source.

Comment: it looks like putting them inside nested tables still has the same issue where it shows up on multiple rows inside the parent table cell

Comment: div's don't work properly in some email clients. Stick with tables. It'll feel like 1999 but at least it will be a bit more consistent

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested tables then you've have two columns (cells) in your outer table e.g.

```
<table> 
<tr> <td>
<table> <tr> <td>First Text</td> <td>Second Text</td> </tr> </table>
</td> <td>
<table> <tr> <td>First Text</td> <td>Second Text</td> </tr> </table>
</td> </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: p.s. it would indeed feel like the 90 :-D